# Primefaces--Add filter to SelectOneListBox

Tags: primefaces, filter

I'd like to know if it's possible to add filter (Starts with for example) to the selectOneListbox in primefaces?

Thank you.

Comment: Does any one know if we can use the autocomplete component with the SelectOneListBox one?

Answer (score 1):

There is no filter shown in the [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneListbox.jsf), neither in the [documentation](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf), so I guess no.

But it is possible to add a filter your own. Unfortunately there is no client side API available for the `selectOneListbox`, so you'd have to filter in your backend. Just put a simple `inputType` over the `selectOneListbox` and everytime you enter a symbol you can update the `selectOneListbox` with the filtered values. But that costs server time, I don't know of that is what you want.

Comment: Yes, i meant by my question if it can be done using javascript for example?

Comment: Yes, but that will be very difficult IMHO, because: take a look at the *Client Side API for SelectOneMenu*. There are methods available for `show`, `hide`, `getSelectedValue` etc. No methods are available for the `selectOneListbox` so that why it's quite difficult, because you would have to write your own `filter()` method yourself. If you are good in javascript, you can definitely do it.